# Sort rows in sub cluster of cluster in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Part  Date         Quantity
A     2023-10-26   -1
A     2023-10-26    1
A     2023-11-03    1
A     2023-12-15   -1
B     2023-11-09    2
B     2023-11-14   -2
B     2023-11-14    2
B     2023-11-19    2
```

Each part is a cluster, and each date within a part is a sub-cluster. I want to order the Quantity values for each date for each part based on: positive values first. Result should be:

```
Part  Date         Quantity
A     2023-10-26    1
A     2023-10-26   -1
A     2023-11-03    1
A     2023-12-15   -1
B     2023-11-09    2
B     2023-11-14    2
B     2023-11-14   -2
B     2023-11-19    2
```

It is possible to use some sort of double groupby, or should I look for a different solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `key` parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with specify column `Quantity` for `False` for positive values by compare by[`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) or [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
out = df.sort_values(['Part', 'Date', 'Quantity'], 
                    key=lambda x: x.le(0) if x.name=='Quantity' else x)
print (out)
  Part        Date  Quantity
1    A  2023-10-26         1
0    A  2023-10-26        -1
2    A  2023-11-03         1
3    A  2023-12-15        -1
4    B  2023-11-09         2
6    B  2023-11-14         2
5    B  2023-11-14        -2
7    B  2023-11-19         2
```

Comment: Works well. On a large dataframe with over 10k unique parts about 100 of them are shuffled around. For me not a problem though, it sticks to the part and date clusters very well.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible solution, which uses a boolean list to define the several sorting orders:

```
df.sort_values(['Part', 'Date', 'Quantity'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```

Output:

```
  Part        Date  Quantity
1    A  2023-10-26         1
0    A  2023-10-26        -1
2    A  2023-11-03         1
3    A  2023-12-15        -1
4    B  2023-11-09         2
6    B  2023-11-14         2
5    B  2023-11-14        -2
7    B  2023-11-19         2
```

Comment: A logical answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort on all values, then [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) is quite efficient:

```
out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['Quantity']<0, df['Date'], df['Part']])]
```

If really you want to sort the values within the groups, not modifying the groups, then you need a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby(['Part', 'Date'], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(by='Quantity', key=lambda x: x<0))
      )
```

Output:

```
  Part        Date  Quantity
1    A  2023-10-26         1
0    A  2023-10-26        -1
2    A  2023-11-03         1
3    A  2023-12-15        -1
4    B  2023-11-09         2
6    B  2023-11-14         2
5    B  2023-11-14        -2
7    B  2023-11-19         2
```

Comment: In essence it works, but on large dataframe very slow.

Comment: @Prmake which one? The numpy approach should be fast, the `groupby` is indeed slow but enables to maintain the groups in place. If the latter point is needed I can provide a faster variant.

Comment: The groupby  is slow indeed. The Lexsort option did not succeed on re-sorting the quantity column in my dataframe. The solution of @jezrael works very well for me.

Comment: @Prmake I'm quite surprised that the lexsort wouldn't work. Have you used it as I wrote it? Can you provide a counterexample?